# How to keep a folder content with git

Tags: git, symfony, amazon-web-services

i need to keep a folder in symfony and aws. In this folder the users upload images, but ever i do a commit this folder content is lost.

web/images

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Git only tracks file (contents).

In order to keep a folder, you need to put a file into it such as `.keepme`. If you need a folder to be automatically created on a clone, the file needs to be tracked, otherwise you can safely add it to a `.gitignore` file in order to ignore it.

Comment: I know the actual name does not matter but I think .gitkeep is more or less a standard?

Comment: @Cerad: `.gitkeep` or—my preferred method—even just an empty `.gitignore`.

Comment: @user1226237 Welcome on stackoverflow. It's common to accept an answer in order to say thank you in case it helped you.